# How to Use Android SkyEpub content provider to use an stream

Tags: android

I want to use skyEpub SDK in my Android application to show my Epubs.
I'm Encrypting my epub files in SDCard and never want to extract them in any physical place (because of security reasons)

I know how to read and decrypt my file into a byte array. But My problem is that I don't know how to send it to the sdk. I've traced the [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpurv1iwj0nxil2/simple_and.zip?dl=0) and found that it extracts the epub file into a directory and then use it , but I don't want to extract raw files in sdcard ever!
I founded that I should implement `ContentListener`  and do something in it but don't know what exactly should do.

Comment: Contact the developers of that SDK and ask them.

Comment: Try this link https://abhishek_patil5@bitbucket.org/abhishek_patil/bookreaderbyskyepub.git